# How to parse through large JSONL data Node js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to read through a large JSONL, maybe couple hundreds up to thousands or possibly million line, below is sample of of the data.

```
{"id":"gid://shopify/Product/1921569226808"}
{"id":"gid://shopify/ProductVariant/19435458986040","__parentId":"gid://shopify/Product/1921569226808"}
{"id":"gid://shopify/Product/1921569259576"}
{"id":"gid://shopify/ProductVariant/19435459018808","__parentId":"gid://shopify/Product/1921569259576"}
{"id":"gid://shopify/Product/1921569292344"}
{"id":"gid://shopify/ProductVariant/19435459051576","__parentId":"gid://shopify/Product/1921569292344"}
{"id":"gid://shopify/Product/1921569325112"}
{"id":"gid://shopify/ProductVariant/19435459084344","__parentId":"gid://shopify/Product/1921569325112"}
{"id":"gid://shopify/Product/1921569357880"}
{"id":"gid://shopify/ProductVariant/19435459117112","__parentId":"gid://shopify/Product/1921569357880"}
{"id":"gid://shopify/ProductVariant/19435458986123","__parentId":"gid://shopify/Product/1921569226808"}
```

So each line is json object, either its a Product, or a Product Child identified by `__parentId`,  given that the data may contain thousands of lines, what's the best way to read through it and return  a regular JSON object, like this.

```
{
"id": "gid://shopify/Product/1921569226808",
"childrens": {
    {"id":"gid://shopify//ProductImage//20771195224224","__parentId":"gid:////shopify//Product//1921569226808"},
    {"id":"gid:////shopify//ProductImage//20771195344224","__parentId":"gid:////shopify//Product//1921569226808"}
    {"id":"gid:////shopify//ProductImage//20771329344224","__parentId":"gid:////shopify//Product//1921569226808"}
}
```

}

The data is coming back from Shopify and they advice to:

> Because nested connections are no longer nested in the response data
> structure, the results contain the __parentId field, which is a
> reference to an object's parent. This field doesn’t exist in the API
> schema, so you can't explicitly query it. It's included automatically
> in bulk operation result.
>
> **Read the JSONL file** in reverse Reading the JSONL file in reverse makes
> it easier to group child nodes and avoids missing any that appear
> after the parent node. For example, while collecting variants, there
> won't be more variants further up the file when you come to the
> product that the variants belong to. After you download the JSONL
> file, read it in reverse, and then parse it so that any child nodes
> are tracked before the parent node is discovered.

You can look for look here to read more about all of this[enter link description here](https://shopify.dev/tutorials/perform-bulk-operations-with-admin-api).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider using streams so that you don't have to load the entire file in memory.

You can use readline (a native module) to process each line individually.

I took the line processing part from @terrymorse https://stackoverflow.com/a/65484413/14793527

```
const readline = require('readline');
const fs = require('fs');

let res = {};

function processLine(line) {
  const {id, __parentId} = line;

  // if there is no `__parentId`, this is a parent
  if (typeof __parentId === 'undefined') {
    res[line.id] = {
      id,
      childrens: []
    };
    return res;
  }
  
  // this is a child, create its parent if necessary
  if (typeof res[__parentId] === 'undefined') {
    res[__parentId] = {
      id: __parentId,
      childrens: []
    }
  }
  
  // add child to parent's children
  res[__parentId].childrens.push(line);
  return res;
}

const readInterface = readline.createInterface({
    input: fs.createReadStream('large.jsonl'),
    output: process.stdout,
    console: false
});

readInterface.on('line', processLine);

readInterface.on('close', function() {
    const resultArray = Object.values(res);
    console.log(resultArray);
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer, struggled a bit to understand the IFs, do you an online reference that can help me boost my data structure skills?

Comment: Isn't this effectively loading the whole content of the file in memory? `res` object will basically contain the whole file, unless I'm missing something

Comment: @Massimo no, it will process data line by line and save only the output.

Comment: @RingoldsLeščinskis that's right, but being `res` the output, what will `res` contain (in memory) at the end of the day according to this algorithm?

Comment: It should contain the generated json object that was mentioned in the original question.

Comment: The line event never seems to fire in my code and I've copied the code exactly. Any idea what might be going on? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a technique that:

1. forms an object with properties of the parent ids
2. converts that object to an array

(input lines converted to an array for simplicity)

```js
const lines = [
  { "id": "gid://shopify/Product/1921569226808" },
  {  "id": "gid://shopify/ProductVariant/19435458986040",  "__parentId": "gid://shopify/Product/1921569226808" },
  { "id": "gid://shopify/Product/1921569259576" },
  { "id": "gid://shopify/ProductVariant/19435459018808", "__parentId": "gid://shopify/Product/1921569259576" },
  { "id": "gid://shopify/Product/1921569292344" },
  { "id": "gid://shopify/ProductVariant/19435459051576", "__parentId": "gid://shopify/Product/1921569292344" },
  { "id": "gid://shopify/Product/1921569325112" },
  { "id": "gid://shopify/ProductVariant/19435459084344", "__parentId": "gid://shopify/Product/1921569325112" },
  { "id": "gid://shopify/Product/1921569357880" },
  { "id": "gid://shopify/ProductVariant/19435459117112", "__parentId": "gid://shopify/Product/1921569357880" },
  { "id": "gid://shopify/ProductVariant/19435458986123", "__parentId": "gid://shopify/Product/1921569226808" }
];

// form object keyed to parent ids
const result = lines.reduce((res, line) => {

  const {id, __parentId} = line;

  // if there is no `__parentId`, this is a parent
  if (typeof __parentId === 'undefined') {
    res[id] = {
      id,
      childrens: []
    };
    return res;
  }
  
  // this is a child, create its parent if necessary
  if (typeof res[__parentId] === 'undefined') {
    res[__parentId] = {
      id: __parentId,
      childrens: []
    }
  }
  
  // add child to parent's children
  res[__parentId].childrens.push(line);
  return res;
}, {});

// convert object to array
const resultArray = Object.values(result);

const pre = document.querySelector('pre');
pre.innerText = 'resultArray: ' + JSON.stringify(resultArray, null, 2);
```

```html
<pre></pre>
```